# Macro compilation error on non-trivial lambda

Tags: scala, lambda, scala-macros

I wanted to write a macro that will inspect and modify a lamba.
For now macro looks like this (it doesn't do any modification):

```
object Macro {
  def literalInt(c: blackbox.Context)(func: c.Expr[Int => Int]): c.Expr[Int => Int] = {
    import c.universe._

    val Function(params, body) = func.tree

    c.Expr(Function(params, body))
  }
  
  def lit(func: Int => Int): Int => Int = macro literalInt

}
```

It works fine for trivial lambdas, like:

```
Macro.lit(_ + 19)
```

but it fails on

```
Macro.lit { args =>
    val temp = 10
    args + temp * 2
}
```

with error:

```
scalac: Error while emitting App.scala
value temp
```

Does anyone know what and why is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read *Macrology 201* about owner chain corruptions

https://github.com/scalamacros/macrology201/tree/part1

https://github.com/scalamacros/macrology201/commits/part1 (especially step 21 and thereafter)

> An easy workaround to the owner chain corruption problem is erasing the
> chunk of the symbol table whose corresponding code is undergoing radical
> transformations. After the symbols in the problematic trees are erased,
> post-expansion typecheck is going to recreate them from scratch, keeping
> the symbol table consistent. This is done by a dedicated macro API called
> `c.untypecheck` in Scala 2.11* and `c.resetLocalAttrs` in Scala 2.10.

(*) And Scala 2.12-2.13.

Try to untypecheck incoming trees (in easy cases this should be enough)

```
def literalInt(c: blackbox.Context)(func: c.Expr[Int => Int]): c.Expr[Int => Int] = {
  import c.universe._

  val Function(params, body) = c.untypecheck(func.tree)

  c.Expr(Function(params, body))
}
```

[Using scala macro to manipulate variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068927/using-scala-macro-to-manipulate-variable-declaration)

[Macro untypecheck required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968925/macro-untypecheck-required)

[What is wrong with this def macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449684/what-is-wrong-with-this-def-macro)

[How to use a `universe.Tree` created and type-checked in one Scala macro execution, in another macro execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64950654/how-to-use-a-universe-tree-created-and-type-checked-in-one-scala-macro-executi)

Comment: Thanks, I followed the links and found a lot of useful information there :)